# Create Excel file with Pivot table from a web page button

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007

I would like to create an excel file on clicking a button on a web page created in .NET. This excel file would have multiple pivot tables. Please let me know if there is a way to create the excel file on button click and if it really necessary to save the file to create the pivot tables. I have created excel file with pivot table on a console application but have not done that in a web application.can the file be created without actually saving the file and giving the user the flexibility to Save/Open it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since you shouldn't install Excel on a server, your best option would be to create and/or manipulate an Excel file using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML, which is the documented XLSX format. You can use the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) to make your life easier.

Once the Excel file has been created/manipulated you can either save it to a temporary location on the server, then return the file via request, and delete the file. This is assuming you use IIS and either WebForms or MVC.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. How do I use Open XML SDK? Does it allow me to create pivot tables in Excel without saving it on server? If possible, please send me a sample code. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your scenario. Do you want to manipulate your Excel spreadsheet in a web page on the client computer? That is not really possible, as your client machine will have to have Excel installed.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for your follow-up. My scenario is as follows:1. Create a button. 2. On click of the button, create an excel file which would many pivot tables in it. Give the user provision to save/open the file. Is it possible to create pivot table on a temporary file without saving the file in some location in the server? Please let me know.